# How to find basis of functions for best representation of function described in several different truncated ON systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, computational-mathematics, least-squares

I have two ON bases where I to the best $L_2$ precision possible represent the same function. Let us say that these have $n_1,n_2$ basis functions respectively for which we know the coefficient perfectly.

***Example***: I have a function which has both a Discrete Fourier Transform and a power series expansion around on $[-1,1]$ and around $0$ respectively.
Say I have both all Fourier coefficients up to $n_1$ and all Monomial coefficients up to $n_2$.

How do I find which family of functions which linear combinations best (in some sense) preserve this knowledge, up to, say $n_3$ terms? I will assume we want $n_3\lt n_2+n_1$, since it would otherwise be quite trivial, as we then could simply stack the representations on top of each other as we don't need to "compress" anything.

Comment: Should everyone know your notation?

Comment: @VorKir There is not so much notation in the question, is there? Not enough to make a special chapter about it anyways.